# Selenium python sometimes not click the button

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I created a loop that clicks some buttons while I'm away from the computer, but every time I go back, I see that the loop has stopped, and I don't understand why I can still click the button:

```
loop = True
while loop:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scheduleForm:dataTableListaAtos:0:bCal"]').click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scheduleForm:j_idt174"]'))).click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_idt277"]').click()
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: You need to update your question with a minimal reproducible example, in order for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @kfir What error do you get. Try printing the error in the except block

Comment: @TalAngel I don't get an error, the loop clicks on the button and then randomly stops.

Comment: @kfir Instead of doing continue, print the error in the except block. This way you will know what is wrong.

Comment: i had this issue unti i figured out that the if condition wasn't correct.
try if rowid < rowscount-1